# Why are there two "hat" keys on an AZERTY keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

The French [AZERTY keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) has two "hat" keys ([circumflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex)).

[image]

The one right to the <kbd>P</kbd> is used to create compound letters, by pressing <kbd>^</kbd>, releasing it and then pressing the letter to decorate.

It does not work with the other one (accessed via <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>), a single `^` is output (this can also be achieved via the compound key via <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>).

Why two keys for one symbol?

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article for AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) has the explanation:

For the **Belgian** AZERTY layout, the circumflex right of the `P` is a dead key that combines with other keys to produce characters with a circumflex, while

> the `^` symbol is generated by a combination of <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>§</kbd> (same key as the 6); but, as opposed to the <kbd>^</kbd> symbol found to the right of the p key, it is not a dead key, and therefore does not generate the placing of a circumflex accent;

Comment: This is the same as in the French keyboard, as I mentioned in my question (except that the second circumflex is AltGr+9)

Comment: I just copied Wikipedia. I am neither French nor Belgian, and I do not know what the standards are, and it may even differ on different OS's (as also described in the Wikipedia article, apparently Apple has a different layout).